# Should I include the control group on a correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation, control-group

I have a dataset of variables from a control group (healthy subjects) and patients with a disease.

Some variables are greatly increased in the disease group in relation to the controls, however within each group there is not much variance.

If I plot the variables with all groups together I get strong correlations due to the progression between groups, but if I plot the groups separately, I only get weak correlations.

So I'm thinking it would make more sense to include all groups in the correlation matrix. Am I wrong?

Comment: What is your goal? Tell us about that, and give more details about the study, then maybe we can help. This looks like It sounds to me like the problem you're trying to solve is 
`<X>`, and you're wondering if `<Y>` is a good way to go 
about it. Is that fair? Because if your real question
is "`<X>`?" then I would suggest only asking about that. As 
its written right now, the question appears to be an 
[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The overall question is how the variables change in the disease state , and for this graph, is  how this changes correlate.